# Collecting same months of each years in the index of dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my monthly data:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-31', end = '2019-12-31', freq='M', name = 'Date')
cfs = pd.DataFrame(\
        [0.36,  0.42,   0.28,   0.31,   0.25,   0.32,   0.42,   0.38,   0.25,   0.31,   0.31,   0.31,
         0.37,  0.36,   0.36,   0.24,   0.26,   0.31,   0.48,   0.45,   0.35,   0.28,   0.35,   0.40,
         0.38,  0.40,   0.31,   0.23,   0.29,   0.22,   0.43,   0.49,   0.24,   0.29,   0.24,   0.46,
         0.38,  0.38,   0.42,   0.25,   0.25,   0.26,   0.29,   0.47,   0.36,   0.30,   0.42,   0.32,
         0.42,  0.40,   0.40,   0.29,   0.22,   0.33,   0.37,   0.50,   0.38,   0.23,   0.25,   0.27], \

    index = date_range, columns = ['Values'])
```

Its output like this:

```
            Values
Date
2015-01-31    0.36
2015-02-28    0.42
2015-03-31    0.28
2015-04-30    0.31
2015-05-31    0.25
2015-06-30    0.32
        ...
2019-09-30    0.38
2019-10-31    0.23
2019-11-30    0.25
2019-12-31    0.27
```

But I want to achieve output like this:

```
            Values
Date
2015-01-31    0.36
2016-01-31    0.37
2017-01-31    0.38
2018-01-31    0.38
2019-01-31    0.42
2015-02-28    0.42
2016-02-29    0.36
2017-02-28    0.40
2018-02-28    0.38
2019-02-28    0.40
2015-03-31    0.28
2016-03-31    0.36
2017-03-31    0.31
        ...
2015-12-31    0.31
2016-12-31    0.40
2017-12-31    0.46
2018-12-31    0.32
2019-12-31    0.27
```

I want to collect all same months of every years and create new dataframe with them. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Combine `iloc` with ...

If you want to just account for `month` and are not concerned with the order of the rows within equivalent months:

#### ... `argsort`

```
cfs.iloc[cfs.index.month.argsort()]

            Values
Date              
2015-01-31    0.36
2017-01-31    0.38
2018-01-31    0.38
2016-01-31    0.37
2019-01-31    0.42
2018-02-28    0.38
2017-02-28    0.40
2019-02-28    0.40
2016-02-29    0.36
2015-02-28    0.42
....
2016-11-30    0.35
2018-11-30    0.42
2017-11-30    0.24
2019-11-30    0.25
2015-11-30    0.31
2018-12-31    0.32
2016-12-31    0.40
2015-12-31    0.31
2017-12-31    0.46
2019-12-31    0.27
```

However, you can preserve the existing order within equivalent months by specifying a stable sorting algoritm.

```
cfs.iloc[cfs.index.month.argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

Otherwise, if you want to consider the year (or any other number of variables)

#### ... `lexsort`

```
cfs.iloc[np.lexsort((cfs.index.year, cfs.index.month))]

            Values
Date              
2015-01-31    0.36
2016-01-31    0.37
2017-01-31    0.38
2018-01-31    0.38
2019-01-31    0.42
2015-02-28    0.42
2016-02-29    0.36
2017-02-28    0.40
2018-02-28    0.38
2019-02-28    0.40
....
2015-11-30    0.31
2016-11-30    0.35
2017-11-30    0.24
2018-11-30    0.42
2019-11-30    0.25
2015-12-31    0.31
2016-12-31    0.40
2017-12-31    0.46
2018-12-31    0.32
2019-12-31    0.27
```

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily assign a `month` column and sort:

```
cfs = cfs.assign(month=cfs.index.month).sort_values('month').drop('month', axis=1)
```

Comment: This can also benefit from a stable sort `cfs.assign(month=cfs.index.month).sort_values('month', kind='mergesort').drop('month', axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Sort `date_range` before making it the index to `cfs`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': date_range.year,
    'month': date_range.month
}, index=date_range)
tmp.sort_values(['month', 'year'], inplace=True)

cfs = pd.DataFrame(..., index=tmp.index)
```